# Issue with jQuery resize for responsive

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, resize, prepend, appendto

I am working on a header for a new site and am having a few issues with using jquery (in combination with media queries) for responsive. My client wants the header to respond to both breakpoints but also as the window is manually resized.  Certain elements are hidden and shown at 1024px window size, but I want this to happen both when a tablet loads the header and on window resize.  My jQuery is as follows...

```
var win = $(window);
            var mainNav = $('.main-nav');
            var navItem = $('.main-nav li');
            var overlay = $('.nav-overlay');
            var header = $('#header');
            var subNav = $('.main-nav ul ul');
            var overlayIsVisible = false;
            var subNavIsVisible = false;
            var exitMain = $('.exit-main');
            var deviceWidth = win.width();
            var topNav = $('.top-nav');
            var hamburger = $('.tablet-buttons .hamburger');
            var exit = $('.tablet-buttons .exit');

                if ( header.is('*') ) {

                    navItem.hover(function() {
                        overlay.fadeIn('slow');
                        $(this).find('ul').toggleClass("active");
                        overlayIsVisible = true;
                    });

                    exitMain.click(function() {
                        overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                        overlayIsVisible = false;
                    })

                    if (win.width() <= 1024) {
                        topNav.prependTo(overlay);
                        mainNav.prependTo(overlay).insertAfter(topNav);
                        hamburger.click(function() {
                            overlay.fadeIn('slow');
                            hamburger.css('display', 'none');
                            exit.fadeIn('slow');
                        });
                        exit.click(function(){
                            overlay.fadeOut('slow');
                            exit.css('display', 'none');
                            hamburger.fadeIn('slow');
                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        topNav.insertAfter('.logo');

                    }

                    /*This makes the above Mobile/Tablet functions also work on resize of window*/

                    win.on('resize', function(){

                        if (win.width() <= 1024) {
                            topNav.prependTo(overlay);
                            mainNav.prependTo(overlay);
                        }
                        else {
                            topNav.insertAfter('.logo');
                            mainNav.prependTo(header);
                        }
                    });
                };
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?  Is there a way I can just write my functions once so that they will happen on both window resize and load.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define your resizing logic in a function saved to a variable, and then you can hook it up to as many events as you need without having to retype it.

Anonymous functions are great because precisely that you can define and pass them around as you need.

```
Var resize = function() { 
     ResizeStuff
     };
```